# Android Arduino Connection

Tags: android, arduino, tags, nfc, tagging

I want to send a text
- From Android Smartphone to Arduino by NFC.

Process is
Text(smartphone) - Tagging NFC Reader(Arduino) - Arduino gets text.

Can I send a text in my phone?

If this is not possible,

Text(smartphone) - Write text to NFC Tag - NFC Reader(Arduino) reads the Tag  - Arduino gets text.

is possible?

I want some example.

If you give me some help, is very appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The Adafruit Arduino NFC shield
allows you to have NFC on your Arduino.

From their description:

> While the controller has many capabilities, our Arduino library currently only supports reading/writing tags, and does not support phone-to-shield communication, tag emulation (which requires an external 'secure element' only available from NXP) or other more advanced features at this time.

You should be able to write data onto a tag, and then read the tag using your Arduino.

You might also want to check out
[this library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-PN532,)
for a few examples, and you may find
[these schematics](http://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/PN532_Breakout_Schematic_v1.0.pdf,)
useful.